# after printf program ends itself without doing the rest of code ? C

Tags: c

after printf line program ends itself but i didnt get it why.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int Sum,multiply,divide,difference,num1,num2;
    char i;
    scanf("%d", &s1);
    scanf("%d", &s2);
    printf("Type initial of your operation : ");
    scanf("%c", &i);

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised you even got that to compile, as `s1` and `s2` appear to be undefined

Comment: Please update your question to show your actual code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you could compile that, since `s1` and `s2` are undefined variables.

Thus, any information about what happened when you ran it is moot, since there is no way you could run it.

You meant:

```
if(scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2) == 2)
{
  printf("Operands are %d and %d, now type initial of desired operation:\n");
  if(scanf("%c", &i) == 1)
  {
  }
}
```

It's important to check that `scanf()` has succeeded before relying on the return value.

Answer (score 1):

use `scanf(" %c",&i);`
there is new line character is present in buffer,so it is not asking for any input and storing it in i.

Answer (score 0):

`s1` & `s2` are not declared which you are trying to read into them. 
I feel they should be `num1` & `num2` which you been declared as integers.

After `printf` you just read a char value into `i` using scanf and main ends doing nothing.